# split string in C and take each field separately

Tags: c, string, strtok, strcpy, split

I want to split a string i have "msg 10 2" into different strings & ints. so instead of having

```
  msg 10 2
```

I can take each as a seperate parameter can print:

```
   msg
   10
   2
```

I use the variable to define a message:

```
  char msg[30] = "msg 10 2";
```

I then want to take each field as seperate values/parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Since you have `strtok` in your tag, so you already know what to do.  What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your string will always follow the format `string int int`, then you could also use [`sscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok` (which you already tagged) and `atoi`.

Comment: i dont know how to use it for this case.

Comment: @user3035890: The [`strtok` reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) has example code of tokenizing a string. [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) simply converts a cstring (`"10"`) to an int (`10`).